# How to solve: "Sorry, cannot split this hunk"?

Tags: git

I've run:

```
git add -p
```

and I then want to split my hunk by typing `s`:

```
 import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
-import org.junit.Ignore;
+import org.junit.Before;
 import org.junit.Test;
 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,j,J,g,/,e,?]? s
Sorry, cannot split this hunk
```

I would like to only add `import org.junit.Before;` to my commit and not to remove `import org.junit.Ignore;`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can manually edit the hunk by typing `e` and then edit the hunk so that it only contains whatever you need (note the space before all imports except the one you want to add):

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
 import org.junit.Ignore;
+import org.junit.Before;
 import org.junit.Test;
 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
```

This way you will get:

- `+import org.junit.Before;` will be in the staging area, ready to be committed (cf. `git diff --cached`)
- `-import org.junit.Ignore;` will be there in the working directory, ready to be added to the staging area or changed (cf. `git diff`)

After committing, your `HEAD` will show (i.e. `git show HEAD`):

```
commit f2d890ec808c4ef35a4e77b7929bcfbc233101b4 (HEAD -> master)
Author: xxx
Date:   Thu Jul 4 19:49:25 2019 +0100

    Second

diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index d1d0b87..462d075 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
 import org.junit.Ignore;
+import org.junit.Before;
 import org.junit.Test;
 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
```

Comment: Do you know what causes git to be unable to split some hunks? Git recently told me that it couldn't split a hunk that was just two consecutive lines added to the file, and I thought that was surprising because I would have assumed that two consecutive added lines would be one of the easiest hunks to split.